# Ubuntu main repository and PHP

Tags: 18.04, package-management, php, ppa, lamp

I’m seeking a “best practice.”  I am building a LAMP server and when it comes to PHP specifically, I noted that the main Ubuntu repository only has version 7.2x while the current version is 7.4x.  7.2x is fine, but when I am reading the PHP configuration documentation for Magento, they are calling for specific PHP extensions which I can’t seem to find in the repo (at least by the given name).  Here’s the documentation with list of extensions:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/php-settings.html

For example, I can’t find a php-devel package, and a couple of others on this list that seem to not install by default from the main repo.  Perhaps they are under a different name?

Is it best to use a PHP PPA instead?  Is this a better practice in general so to be sure my software is current?  Security fixes and the like?

Your guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The older PHP versions in the Ubuntu repositories receives the SAME security patches as newer upstream versions, courtesy of the [Ubuntu Security Team](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam). Pull the Team's CVE tracker and see for yourself. They [podcast](https://ubuntusecuritypodcast.org/) frequently about the many patches that PHP requires. The message "use-the-newest-version-it's-safest" is for users who roll their own and don't patch...or use PPAs, which are maintained (or not) by somebody else.

Comment: The devel package you seek is likely `php7.2-dev`. Alternately, you can use `php-all-dev` to always pull in the correct version.